# When is the right time for kegging?

Tags: kegging

Hi I am about to keg for 1st time and my question is this do we force carbonate right after fermentation is over?For example a lager beer style will go for laggering before or after 
force carbonation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually keg and carbonate my lagers after 4 weeks or so in primary.  As long as fermentation is finished, you can keg, carb and lager at any time and do them all simultaneously.

Comment: Why do you keep it in the fermenter that long? I bottle or keg both lagers and ales when fermentation is done and then let them clarify / lager / age in the bottle or keg for 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Several reasons...at the low temps I use to ferment lagers, it takes that long for them to ferment out.  Also, by giving the yeast plenty of time to work, I almost never get diacetyl.

Answer (score 2):

You keg the beer at the same time you would bottle. So, for an ale, keg after the beer has fermented and clarified. For lagers, after the lagering period is finished.

Comment: "For lagers, after the lagering period is finished." - Tons of folks do their lagering in a keg (myself included). I only secondary my lagers long enough to let that first wave of sediment drop out of suspension (2-3 weeks). After that, its into the keg for the real lagering process.

Comment: Do you drop the temp slowly? I understand this can be helpful for keeping the yeast active during the layering phase.

Comment: Dropping slowly is only a requirement if you are still wanting the yeast to clean up diacytl. You can raise temps during the end of primary for the D-rest, and then crash immediately to lagering temps in the keg.